# MySQL : Auto generate view depending on table content

Tags: mysql, view, triggers

I have a database in which I have a table which contains electronic components. I'd like to create view depending on the type of the component.

Let's say my table as 2 fields :

- Category
- Sub category

Now let's say that I have many radial Rasistor in my table. They all have Category : Resistor, Sub Category : Radial.
I would like to execute a query like this :

```
CREATE VIEW `Resistor - Radial` AS SELECT * FROM `components` WHERE `Category`='Resistor' AND `Sub Category`='Radial'
```

This is easy. Now I would like to auto-generate theses view everytime a user enter a new part, delete a part or modify an existing one. I thought about trigger, but don't know a lot about them. Would trigger be a good approach ?

Comment: Why do you want to create these `view`s ?

Comment: Because my PCB software connect to that database and recognize tables. Views are the correct way to build this systems.

Comment: @user2302957 . . . You really can't use a simple `where` clause for this?

Comment: No, I can't. My software look for tables, it doesn't allow me to edit my own SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "ideal" answer to your question would be to have an insert trigger on the table that and then have this trigger create a view.  But, in order to create a view with a user-generated name, you would need to use dynamic SQL.  [And this is not support in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Another solution would be a user-defined function that returns a table.  But that is also not part of MySQL.

So, if you really want to do this, then I can think of two options.  The first is to wrap all inserts into the table in a stored procedure.  A stored procedure can then call dynamic SQL to create the view.

The other is to have a daily (hourly?  minutely?) job that looks for new records in the table.  When a new combination is found, then create the view.

Comment: That's a lot of useful info. Regarding what you proposed, I think the best would be a daily job that recreate the views. Thanks